# Running Debian from SD card slot in dl380 G6. Yes or no?

Tags: debian, hp-proliant, operating-system, nextcloud, sd-card

I would like to run Debian 10 OS from the SD card slot in dl380 G6. It's a minimal install.

I will run nextcloud on this server for personal use which will be ofcourse on the disks. I was wondering if this is a good idea so I don't loose my drive space.

Also if yes: install nextcloud on the drives or on the SD card. Data folder will ofcourse be on the drives.

If no: well that means that Debian would have to many writes to the SD card that would result in failure.

So the question is yes or no?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use the disks in the server chassis?

Comment: Have you considered running e.g. [Alpine Linux in diskless mode](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Installation#Diskless_Mode)? That may be more suited for such an deployment.

Answer (score 1):

Use the internal disks.

You have an HPE server with a SmartArray controller. You can carve a "Logical Volume" (aka Logical Drive) out of your main data disks to provide a small block device for the OS, then another Logical Volume for your data.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple yes/no answer here. It can work, and may be a valid choice in some situations.

Consider, there are tons of people running a Debian variant on Raspberry Pi hardware, which uses a SD card as the primary storage. So it is certainly possible to run of an SD card.

SD media will probably be less reliable then an expensive enterprise SSD, and won't be fast. But if you get a good card that is suggested as being good to use for a Raspberry Pi, then it will probably work for some use cases.

As with everything, have external backups of your data is strongly suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I have run a home automation server on an RPi for 5 years using a micro SD card.  The OS is raspbian, which is really debian for ARM chipset.The system has multiple read/writes every second and pretty consistently the SD cards fail at around the 18 month mark, even with high quality cards.

So debian can run from an SD card, provided your system bios can boot from the sd card.

I can understand why you would want to separate the OS from the data files.  However, you should consider putting the high read/write directories on the main disk - eg: /var /tmp/ /home.

Also check where nextcloud writes its files and logs to as they may be in the sd card filesystem by default.

HTH